# How to install Terracotta TIM / DSO on server without internet?

Tags: java, linux, ehcache, terracotta

I have installed Terracotta on my server, and I can start it up. We are using tim-ehcache though so I also need to generate the dso-boot-jar, as per this page: http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/more/terracotta-dso/dso-install (Step 3: Install the TIMs). However, the server on which I have installed Terracotta does not have access to the internet, and when running the tim-get.sh script it is unable to connect to the internet and fails.

Is there a way to download the files required and put them somewhere locally? Or is there somewhere where I can download the dso-boot jar fully formed? (My understanding is that it is very sensitive to a specific version of JAVA... is it also sensitive to OS? Could I install the same version of JAVA on my Windows server, build the boot-dso jar, and copy it over onto my Linux server?)

I can see when I try to run the tim-get.sh script, that it complains that "cannot load remote index file [...] cannot resolve local cached copy" - so I downloaded the index.xml.gz file that it looks for, and put it in the /tmp/tim-get/ folder where it is looking for local cached copy. Now it complains:

```
No module found matching: tim-ehcache-2.x:latest groupId=org.terracotta.modules
Found no module to install.
```

Why can it not find module to install? I have found on the terracotta repository the library tim-ehcache-2.x-1.8.7.jar that it should be looking for based on the info in the index file, but what do I do with it? Can I put it somewhere locally and make the file use it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just a word of caution as you might be installing this to learn TC: DSO is deprecated and is not maintained any more from TC 4.

Comment: Thanks Augusto, I am trying to learn but based on a solution that a client provides so I don't have much choice of framework - what exactly is DSO? Is there a simple, 'in english' page I can read that explains what it's for? I have tried searching but it all seems to be jargon...

Comment: DSO is a monster that TC created some years ago and convinced a lot of companies that was the future of **distributed caches**. Some poor decision makers bought that snake oil, and developers cried; somtimes DSO does very little and sometimes too much to hide the complexity of distributed systems. Some years later, TC realised the error and acquired Ehcache as the new interface for TC and deprecated DSO. </RandOver> DSO stands for **Distributed Shared Objects** and is a horrible thing that can hijack your application and transforms it to a distributed one - What can go wrong?